# Disable CDN REDIRECT

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, hosting, cdn

I'm on litespeed server(Shared Hosting), I want disable CDN Redirect to make links to my wordpress images a direct links without CDN for Example:

https://sportnews.dz/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/boiudabouzz248.jpg

But, when the url is accessed, it's redirected to an url with CDN:

https://**cdn.**sportnews.dz/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/boiudabouzz248.jpg

Thank you very much.

-I tried to disable CDN from CPANEL but no option for that.
-I tried Disabling Litespeedcach Plugin from Wordpress Still the same.
-I don't have other CDN connected to my hosting like ... Cloudflare.

Comment: Rather than just disabling the plugin, you should probably explicitly turn off CDN use in the settings. https://docs.litespeedtech.com/lscache/lscwp/cdn/

Comment: Hi @Cbroe Thank you for your answerTried that but plugin settings are not taking effect, I uploaded an image via FTP into public_html  https://sportnews.dz/image.jpg but it redirect to https://cdn.sportnews.dz/image.jpg I think it's hoting side setting